# RSS == Atom? Issues when getting/parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, node.js, rss

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'http://themeforest.net/feeds/items/3042144.atom', 
        dataType : 'xml', 
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('Failed to parse feed');
        },
        success : function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseXML(data);
        }
    });
```

With this setup I'm getting the error message **"Failed to parse feed"**

When I change the ***dataType*** to ***text*** instead of ***xml***, I successfully fetch the feed, but then ***$.parseXML*** throws error in the console:

```
[ERROR] 21:27:34 Error
Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>tag:themeforest.net,2007-12-31:/feeds/items/1358600</id>
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried googling about it, but couldn't find a similar issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of obvious solution, the **data** variable was already an xml object, so I could traverse it with jquery:

```
$(data).find('entry').find('author').text();
```